# UTC Offset of Client on First/Single Page Load Using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, utc

I am using the following to determine UTC offset and pass it to a PHP variable (`$utc_offset`).  The problem is that `$utc_offset` will only have a value on the second page load (empty on first page load).  How can I pass the UTC offset to PHP in one page load?

```
    <script>
    var dateVar = new Date();
    var offset = dateVar.getTimezoneOffset();
    document.cookie = "offset="+offset/60;
    </script>

    <?php
    echo $utc_offset = $_COOKIE['offset'];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So:

- user first visits the page
- a request is sent to the server
- the server sends content to the user, including Javascript code
- the Javascript code will generate a cookie
- on subsequent loads that cookie is correct (but not on the first load)

The thing is that in order to execute your Javascript, you will need to send it out to the browser and at that point the cookie that you need is not created yet. However, even though you cannot resolve this on first load, you can achieve almost similar behavior, by sending an [AJAX request](https://www.w3schools.com/pHP/php_ajax_php.asp) just after you create the cookie, so the server will get it.

You will therefore need to handle first visit, when the offset is not known, but an AJAX request, sent automatically to the server just afterwards solves this issue.